# authentification using ajax/jsp in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

```
 <form method="POST" class="userform" id="loginForm">
    <div data-role="content">
      <h2> Login:</h2>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input name="email" placeholder="put your name" type="email" data-mini="true">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input name="password" placeholder="enter your password" type="password" data-mini="true">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" data-theme="a" value="submit" id="submitButton">
        <h5 align="center">
            <a href="user_rbooks.html"> Forget password? </a>
        </h5>
        </div>
        </form>
```

this is my login.js

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};

var $bro = $('#loginForm');

$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
        //console.log("submit button has been clicked");
        e.preventDefault(); //cancel form submit

        var jsObj = $bro.serializeObject()
            , ajaxObj = {};

        //console.log(jsObj);

        ajaxObj = {  
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.0.100:8080/AdvancedLibrarySystem/api/v1/login", 
            data: JSON.stringify(jsObj), 
            contentType:"application/json",
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error " + jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() + " " + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
                if(data[0].status == '200') {
                    alert("Welcome!!!")
                    $('#div_ajaxResponse').text( data[0] );
                    $.mobile.changePage('home.html');
                }
                else{
                alert("Incorret Username or Password!!!")
                }

            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                //console.log( XMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders() );
            }, 
            dataType: "json" //request JSON
        };

        $.ajax(ajaxObj);
    });
```

I'm trying to use an authentification in phonegap via ajax but if i'm trying to run that code in chrome console it works fine but when i'm using it in my phonegap application it's not giving response in the server... Anyone can help me out please...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by 'not giving response in the server', but one thing worth checking out is the cross-domain options in the config.xml of your phonegap project. There should be an "access" tag in there that specifies what domains can be accessed. Try setting it to "*" and try again.

Comment: my "access" tag i set it to access all the domains that's mean <access origin="*"/>